# Send sms to mobile number

Tags: c#, sms

I want to send an sms to a mobile number of India. I am using this code.

```
MailMessage message= new MailMessage("FROM SENDER", "9456734352@messaging.sprintpcs.com", "Message Subject", "My Message Data");
SmtpClient mySmtpClient=new SmtpClient("mail.xyz.com");
mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True;
mySmtpClient.Send(message);
MessageBox.Show("Message sent successfully");
```

I am getting error message

```
The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.
```

As I am new to this, so I don't have much Idea about it! What could I do to make this work ?

**EDIT :**

Error

```
Failure sending mail
```

Comment: Are you giving valid email address is first parameter? Also the title of question says SMS but you code si able Email?

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue, but now I am getting `Failure sending mail` error

Comment: you want to send SMS or Email??

Comment: You are sending an email. Are you using a service that converts it to a SMS? If so, who?

Comment: I looked a tutorial here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/TextMsgToCellPhone12112006002339AM/TextMsgToCellPhone.aspx to send sms.

Comment: SMTP is a mail server.. If you want to send SMS to mobile.. then you have to use a SMS gateway.. You can use your personal mobile to send SMS via C# app. You attach your mobile via USB cable to PC.. and then get the COM port and use AT commands to send SMS to the recipients number

Answer (score 2):

You can use AT commands and your personal phone to send as many SMS you want.. You just have to get the COM port assigned to your phone when it is connected to your PC via USB cable

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.serialPort = new SerialPort();
     this.serialPort.PortName = "COM5";
     this.serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
     this.serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
     this.serialPort.DataBits = 8;
     this.serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
     this.serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
     this.serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
     this.serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
     this.serialPort.NewLine = System.Environment.NewLine;
     serialPort.Open();
     send_sms();
 }
 public bool send_sms()
 {
     String SMSMessage = "gsm MESSAGE FROM .NET C#";
     String CellNumber = "+913333333333";

     if (serialPort.IsOpen)
     {
         this.serialPort.WriteLine(@"AT" + (char)(13));
         Thread.Sleep(200);
         this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + (char)(13));
         Thread.Sleep(200);
         this.serialPort.WriteLine(@"AT+CMGS=""" + CellNumber + @"""" + (char)(13));
         Thread.Sleep(200);
         this.serialPort.WriteLine(SMSMessage + (char)(26));
         return true;
     }
     serialPort.Close();
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am using this app on the server where I cannot attach the mobile. I need some other way without using mobile. It would be great if you can show an example using gateway.